# How to call dll methods in a node.js application? (Parameter count mismatch)

Tags: c#, node.js, dll, edgejs

I am trying to use a c# .dll from my node.js application.  I am using the [edge-js library](https://github.com/agracio/edge-js) to accomplish this.

I am able to load the dll but cannot manage to call its methods.
The error I am getting is

> Error: Parameter count mismatch.
> at anonymous:1:55

If anyone can explain how Edge bindings/parameter passing works, it would be appreciated.

dll code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PortableClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public String helloworld(){
            Debug.WriteLine("Hello dll world");  
            return("Hello dll World!");
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my (simplifed) node.js code:

```
"use strict";
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { Console } = require("console");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
 var edge = require("edge-js");
  var helloDll = edge.func({
    assemblyFile: "bin/PortableClassLibrary1.dll",
    typeName: "PortableClassLibrary1.Class1",
    methodName: "helloworld",
  });
  helloDll(null, function (error, result) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
  });

});


module.exports = router;
```

I have also tried synchronous calls:

```
  var returnResult = helloDll(true);
  var returnResult = helloDll(null, true);
```

with the same results.

I looked at these links but they did not help.

- [Assemble .NET dll in Node.js using edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204177/assemble-net-dll-in-node-js-using-edge)
- [How can I use ActiveX DLL in c# code snippet for node js using edge js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607384/how-can-i-use-activex-dll-in-c-sharp-code-snippet-for-node-js-using-edge-js)
- [Can't call method inside C# DLL from node service using Edge.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841697/cant-call-method-inside-c-sharp-dll-from-node-service-using-edge-js)
- [How to call functions in a C# dll file from a node.js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643545/how-to-call-functions-in-a-c-sharp-dll-file-from-a-node-js-file)
- [Using a .NET DLL in Node.js / serverside javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653433/using-a-net-dll-in-node-js-serverside-javascript)
- [How C# dlls methods expose in node js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35452387/how-c-sharp-dlls-methods-expose-in-node-js)

So how about it?  Anyone know how to call .dll methods using edge-js?

Comment: You're calling an instance method. You need an instance to call it on (which is likely the missing parameter) No clue how that works with this library. Try making it a static method and see what happens

Comment: I made it static and got a different error: System.InvalidOperationException
Unable to access the CLR method to wrap through reflection. Make sure it is a public instance method

Answer (score 1):

"helloworld" method in the dll should return a Task and accept an input parameter.

I have modified the code as below and it worked for me.

```
    public async Task<object> helloworld(dynamic input)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Hello dll world");
        // Ignore the compiler warning about await keyword as this just a demo code..
        return "Hello from.NET world !!";
    }
```